# Assign Null value of DataTable Column to int variable in c#

Tags: c#, sql

I have null value in datatable and looking to put this null value in integer variable.

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Initial Catalog=test;Data Source=test;user id=sa;password=****;");
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
con.Open();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from table1", con);

da.Fill(dt);

for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    **int? ii = dt.Rows[i];**
    if (ii == null)
    {
        test.Text = ii.ToString() + "Test";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just check null and not put anything in target variable? Afterall its just a null!

Comment: Besides, then won't `ii.ToString()` throw a nullReference Exceoption?  You know, because `ii` is null and all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several fundamental errors in your code. Below are some of the errors explained, and in the end of the answer is suggestion how to rewrite your code.

---

You are trying to get data from row, and now from a cell. Data is stored in row cells:

```
var row = dt.Rows[i]; // row contains several columns, you have to get from specific column
var ii = dt.Rows[i]["iiColumnName"];
```

---

You are using method of `null` object. If ii is `null` and you try to call it's method, an exception will be thrown and application will crash

```
if (ii == null)
{
    test.Text = ii.ToString() + "Test"; // This will throw NullReferenceException
}
```

---

You are checking to see if for value existence by comparing to `null`. Cell value is never `null` in DataTable. Value is instead `DBNull.Value`. Hence, you check if value is set in one of two following ways:

```
if (ii is DBNull) { /* do something */ }
if (ii == DBNull.Value) { /* do something */ }
```

---

Code which does something you want (hopefully) looks something like this:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Initial Catalog=test;Data Source=test;user id=sa;password=****;");
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
con.Open();
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from table1", con);

da.Fill(dt);

for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DataRow row = dt.Rows[i];
    int? ii;
    if (row["iiColumnName"] is DBNull)
        ii = null;
    else
        ii = (int)row["iiColumnName"];

    if (ii != null)
        test.Text = ii.ToString() + "Test";
    else
        test.Text = "ii is not set";
}
```

Comment: yes you are right here, but i in my actual app i have to assign that null value to integer and apply some checks on it.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Previous code should have gave you idea how to fix it.

Comment: int? ii = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dt.Rows[i][0].ToString()) ? Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i][0]) : (int?)null;

Comment: I use Nulable here int? there is no error if (ii==null)

Answer (score -1):

Casting it to an `int?`

```
int? ii = dt.Rows[i] as int?;
```

If the `dt.Rows[i]` value is not an `int`, ii will be null if not it will be the integer value stored in `dt.Rows[i]`.

Comment: int? ii = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dt.Rows[i][0].ToString()) ? Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i][0]) : (int?)null;